# Alexa skill doesn't send data to firebase (Cloud Firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am doing my project in alexa developer console and I am trying to send data to firebase (Firestore), but apparently it does not leave me. The code `db.collection ('notes').add ({...});` It is practically invisible to the console.

- I authorized the rules of writing and reading in firebase.
- I put the firebase-admin dependency in the package-json

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./key-firebase.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://notes-alexa.firebaseio.com"
});


const db = admin.firestore();
```

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {


        // ----- This code sends the data to firebase. But apparently it doesn't run ----

        db.collection('notes').add({name: "Finn", country: "US"});


        let speakOutput = `Hello world`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse(); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive just compared your code with mine thats working successfully.  The differences I see are below in **bold**:

**async** handle(handlerInput) {....

**await** db.collection('notes').add....

hope it helps!